# Serializing a HashTable, Java

Tags: java, serialization

I have never used Serialization before. I think I have it all right except the last part in my "Q" case-switch.

```
public class Test{

public static void main(String args[]){

    Store store = new Store();

    FileOutputStream fos;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

    try{

        fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("table.obj"));
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

    }catch(IOException e1){

        e1.printStackTrace();

    }
```

This goes on to contain a bunch of more code but what I think is really important is my "Q" case...

```
case "Q":

            System.out.println("Good-Bye!");

            try{

                oos.writeObject(store);
                oos.flush();
                oos.close();

            }catch(IOException e){

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            System.exit(0);

            break;
```

When I attempt to save all the data to my .obj file and close the streams and exit my program I get all these errors...

**java.io.NotSerializableException: Item
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Hashtable.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at Test.main(Test.java:143)**

I'm not sure what most of these errors mean or why I am getting them or even how to fix them. Can anyone help me?

EDIT: STORE CLASS

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Hashtable;

 public class Store implements Serializable{

Hashtable<String, Item> stockedItems = new Hashtable<String, Item>();

public boolean addItem(String code){

    if(stockedItems.containsKey(code)){

        stockedItems.get(code).incrementQuantity();

        return true;

    }

    return false;

}

public boolean removeItem(String code){

    if(stockedItems.containsKey(code)){

        stockedItems.get(code).decrementQuantity();

        return true;

    }

    return false;


}

public boolean findItem(String code){

    if(stockedItems.containsKey(code)){

        return true;

    }

    return false;

}

 }
```

**My HashTable holds Item Objects which do not implement Serializable. Which I now fixed. Program runs and Q case works fine! Now it is my U case that does not work and here it is...

```
case "U":

            try{

                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("table.obj");
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

                store = (Store)ois.readObject();

                ois.close();

            }catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException e){

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            break;
```

The purpose of this case is to allow the user to choose whether or not they want to use the data stored in my .obj file or not. I get these errors upon attempting to use that case

**at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at Test.main(Test.java:142)**

Comment: Can you post the Store class? My guess is that it is not marked as serializable or something within is not serializable.

Comment: Are the objects that you're attempting to store, serializable?

Comment: `NotSerializableException` means you are trying to serialize something that's not serializable. Show your `Store` class...

Comment: I do not see a `Hashtable` at all... and what about the `Store` class?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even if the `Hashtable` object is serializable, the objects that you are storing *inside* it must be serializable as well. So I would first check to see if whatever you're storing inside your `Hashtable` implements the `Serializable` interface. At the very least, your `Store` class should also implement the `Serializable` interface.

**UPDATE**

Based on your updated question, it looks like the `Item` class will need to implement `Serializable` as well. In fact, this is exactly what the first line of the exception says:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: Item
```

Comment: This is better meant as a comment than an answer, IMO

Comment: @hd1 OP asked why he was getting these errors... I explained why and how to fix it. :) IMO that is an answer.

Comment: IMO, it is not an answer, but we'll have to agree to disagree

Comment: Technically the question is _Can anyone help me?_ and the answer is `yes`.

Comment: @hd1 Fair enough; I feel that it answers the question.

Comment: I would've answered this way, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can only write objects that are `Serializable` and you can look up Oracle's JavaDoc for that and learn the details.

In general, you add `implements Serializable` to any class that meets a few requirements, in most cases.

A class has to only have fields that are either themselves Serializable objects or some of the raw types like `int` or `char`, etc.

If there are fields that are of some super-type, the object instance occupying that field has to be Serializable even though the super-type isn't.

There is lots more to it.

Answer (score 1):

"java.io.NotSerializableException: Item" is saying that `class Item` is not serializable.  It needs to be serializable because the contents of a map need to be serializable for the whole map to be serializable.